# Error while editing layout files

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

Since updating to version 3.0.1 of MonoDevelop, I've been unable to work with layout files. When I create a new layout file and then try to edit it from the "Source" tab, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Layout not yet loaded
at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerSession.SetLayoutXml (System.String xml, Boolean allowUndo) [0x000bf] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerSession.cs:353 
at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.Gui.LayoutSourceEditorView.SaveContent () [0x00025] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/Gui/AndroidDesignerView.cs:641 
at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.Gui.LayoutSourceEditorView.Deselected () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/Gui/AndroidDesignerView.cs:670 
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.SdiWorkspaceWindow.SetCurrentView (Int32 newIndex) [0x00032] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/SdiWorkspaceWindow.cs:571 
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.SdiWorkspaceWindow+<AddButton>c__AnonStoreyB0.<>m__169 (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00033] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/SdiWorkspaceWindow.cs:488 
at MonoDevelop.Components.Tab.OnActivated (System.EventArgs e) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components/Tabstrip.cs:396 
at MonoDevelop.Components.Tab.Activate () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components/Tabstrip.cs:244 
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.SdiWorkspaceWindow.ActiveDocumentChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/SdiWorkspaceWindow.cs:501 
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void__this___object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.OnDocumentChanged (System.Object s, System.EventArgs a) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/Workbench.cs:606 
at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.DefaultWorkbench.OnActiveWindowChanged (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00075] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui/DefaultWorkbench.cs:749
at Gtk.Notebook.SwitchPageSignalCallback (IntPtr arg0, IntPtr arg1, UInt32 arg2, IntPtr gch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I haven't found a bug indicating others are experiencing this. Could it be a configuration issue of some sort in my environment? I'm using Mono for Android 4.2.1.196198126.

Comment: This bug has been reported at bugzilla.xamarin.com: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5209

Comment: Could you please answer and accept it, or close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was addressed in version 3.0.2 of MonoDevelop.
http://monodevelop.com/Download/Release_Notes/Release_Notes_for_MonoDevelop_3.0.2